# Implementing both OnTouchListener and LongPressListener to a view

Tags: java, android, android-view

Im trying to add multiple listeners to a my view. OnTouchListener Events get fired but not the long press events. Any reason why? How do i solve it? :)

Here is my source:

```
bookFlipper.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v){ //not fired
        Log.d(tag, "Long press invoked!");
        //selectText();
        return true;
    }
});

bookFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

        if(!menuShown && !selectionMode){
            bookFlipper.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        switch(event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(selectionMode){

            }
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastDownX = event.getX();
            lastDownY = event.getX();
            touchingBook = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchingBook = false;
            if(!selectionMode){
                float diff = event.getX() / screenWidth;
                float diffOld = lastDownX / screenWidth;
                if(diff <= 0.33 && diffOld <= 0.33 && !menuShown){ // left
                    prevPage();
                }else if(diff >= 0.66 && diffOld >= 0.66 && !menuShown){// right
                    nextPage();
                }else if(diff < 0.66 && diff > 0.33 && diffOld < 0.66 && diffOld > 0.33){ // middle
                    showOverlay(!menuShown);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using `GestureDetectorCompat`

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Example:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html